# C - GetVersionEx reports wrong version

Tags: c, windows

I wrote some code to get the Windows version, utilizing the [`GetVersionEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx) function. Here it is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    OSVERSIONINFO ver;
    ZeroMemory(&ver, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO));
    ver.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);
    GetVersionEx(&ver);
    printf("Version is %i.%i build %i", ver.dwMajorVersion, 
    ver.dwMinorVersion, ver.dwBuildNumber); 
}
```

When run on my Windows 10 Pro build 15063 system, it reports that the program is run on a Windows 8.1 build 9200 system.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is it by any chance running in compatibility mode?

Comment: Yes, I do think so; by changing it to be compatible with Vista via properties it reports so.

Comment: There are a lot of existing questions about this.  But the correct resolution depends on *why* you're trying to get the version number, which you haven't explained.

Comment: @RbMm, if too many people start using `RtlGetVersion` then it *will* be hobbled in some future release of Windows, for the same reason `GetVersionEx` was hobbled in Windows 8.